# DateInput: how to show placeholder

Tags: django, django-models

**Django 1.10**

I have a model in fields of which I prefer null=False. 
But those default values become default values in the form. This is dangerous: blank=False validation no more available.

I have created a form with two purposes:

1. Clear default values.
2. Show the placeholder.

But the result is that html renders without placeholders. I have also tried TextInput without success.
Could you help me understand how to cope with this problem?

```
class Masterphoto(models.lModel):
    dated_from = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, default=datetime.date(2000, 1, 1))
    dated_to = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, default=datetime.date(2000, 1, 1))

class MasterphotoForm(ModelForm):
    dated_from = forms.DateField()
    dated_to = forms.DateField()


    class Meta:
        model = Masterphoto
        exclude = []
        widgets = {
            'dated_from': forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'YYYY-MM-DD'}),
            'dated_to': forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'YYYY-MM-DD'}),         
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using:

`forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'required': 'required'}))`

We do something very similar to this for our forms where we want to show a sample date for format and it doesn't ruin the form validation in the event someone tries to insert a blank value.